# Proof of Inequality Of Expectation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value

I am looking at a proof for subgaussian random variables but can't make sense for one of the steps:

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(aX^2)]\le 1 + \int_0^{\infty}2at\cdot\exp (at^2)\mathbb{P}(|X|>t) \, dt$$

Can someone help clarify how this inequality is derived.

Edit: $a>0$

Comment: $Ef(|X|)=\int_0^{\infty} f'(t)P(|X|>t)dt$ by Fubini's Theorem for a positive smooth function $f$. . Use this and split the integral into integral from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is a special case of the following general formula:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ a probability space and $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable with $X\geq 0$. Then, for every continuously differentiable function $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ with $\phi'\geq 0$, we have the following:
> $$\tag{1}\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]=\phi(0)+\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi'(t)\mathbb{P}\bigl(X>t\bigr)\,dt$$

The proof $(1)$ is based on Tonelli's theorem and the fundemental theorem of calculus: Denote by $F_X(x)$ the c.d.f function of $X$, then ($X$ is nonnegative)
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)dF_X(x)
\end{align}
Fix some $x$ and write $\phi(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\phi'(t)dt+\phi(0)$. Substituting in $(2)$ we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)dF_X(x)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\int_{0}^{x}\phi'(t)dt\biggr)dF_x(x)+\phi(0)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\biggl(\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi'(t)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{t<x\}}dt\biggr)dF_X(x)+\phi(0)\tag{3}
\end{align}
Now, the function $(t,x)\mapsto \phi'(t)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{t<x\}}$ is nonnegative. Using Tonelli's theorem in $(3)$ and interchange the order of integration, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]&=\int_0^\infty\biggl(\int_0^\infty\phi'(t)\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{t<x\}}\,dF_X(x)\biggr)dt+\phi(0)\\&=\int_0^\infty\phi'(t)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X>t)\,dt+\phi(0)
\end{align}
and $(1)$ is proven. Now, using $(1)$ with $\phi(t)=e^{\alpha t^2}$ and as nonnegative random variable the absolute value $|X|$ of $X$ you get the inequality you want and in fact its an equality.